# Generating an Excel File Example for Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I've come across [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) and I found a couple of examples of using it, but none seem to work, they've all got some aspect, component missing or are for a different version of Visual Studio. I simply need to generate a `.xls` or `.xlsx` or even a `.csv` file, but as I am using a 3rd party server I can't use the Office .com objects. I have used [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) in the past which is expensive and as I am retired, I can't afford this sort of product.

If anyone has a working example of ExcelPackage or any other freeware offering, or can point me in the direction of one that has everything I need, it would be appreciated. A regular Web App rather than MVC would be preferred.

Comment: You didn't want to use the COM objects. They either don't work at all, or are flaky, and  unsupported in a server, and may violate your Office license.

Comment: CSV is just plain text - you can do that without any components...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Simplexcel](https://github.com/mstum/Simplexcel) by [Michael Stum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91/michael-stum). It is designed around simplicity, is fully supported under ASP.net and should allow you to make simple, but extremely usable Excel cheats. You have an simple example available [here](https://github.com/mstum/Simplexcel/blob/master/src/Simplexcel.TestApp/Program.cs).

Comment: This looks like it will do the job, but I am am new to this sort of thing and it is trying to save to the server. How do I get the file that is generated on the server to save to my local PC? I have looked around the net and I can only find examples of saving existing files, not on the fly generated files.

Comment: Tthat is a bit outside of the scope of your original question. I would recommend opening a new question for taht, but you could probably do something like this.
`MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
wb.Save(stream, CompressionLevel.Maximum);
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel");`
Basically storing the result in Memory, and then using `FileStreamResult` to return it in ASP.net.

Comment: Ok, thanks eanderason. I will do just that. I am not using MVC and FileStreamResult is an MVC component, so need something for webforms. I suspect it is going to use HTTP handlers.

Comment: You can do the same for WinForms. Would sending them as an email be an option?

Comment: I can't use winforms, but an email would be a non-preferred option. I can't store the file though on the server.

Comment: Ah, my bad misread your previous comment. I think this should be for ASP.net. I haven't really used plain ASP.net myself. ;)

`Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.OutputStream.Write(stream, 0, stream.Length);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=yourfile.xls");`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072814/c-sharp-asp-net-write-file-to-client

Comment: If you start a new question I can probably try to show you some more extensive examples on how to send files through webforms using a stream in a plain `ASP.net`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I have started a new  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589162/asp-net-webform-generated-excel-file-to-local-pc-and-not-server

Comment: I updated my answer on your second question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589162/asp-net-webform-generated-excel-file-to-local-pc-and-not-server/15589598#15589598 with a complete example. =]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124). This gives you the ability to [generate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440953%28v=office.12%29) and manipulate Office documents without using Office itself or the interop, and as such makes it a suitable approach from the server-side.