# ASP.Net webform generated Excel File to local PC and not server

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webforms

Following on from a question about generating Excel files, I need to be able to create the file locally while the webform app is located on the remote web server. This is not anything I've dealt with before, so I am finding it difficult exactly what to ask. I am using WebForms on VS2010 with c#. [eanderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408182/eandersson) pointed me in the direction of
[Simplexcel](https://github.com/mstum/Simplexcel) by [Michael Stum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91/michael-stum) which seems to do the trick but the file is generated on the server (or should I says 'tries to' as it is not permitted!!!).

Comment: Can't you generate the excel file in the TEMP folder and then stream it back? Let's first try to fix the file generation issue... Can you show the line of code that Save to a particular file?

Comment: Creating the file is not a problem, it is saving it locally as I can't on the server. My code is `var sheet = new Worksheet("Hello, world!");
        sheet.Cells[0, 0] = "Hello,";
        sheet.Cells["B1"] = "World!";

        var workbook = new Workbook();
        workbook.Add(sheet);
        workbook.Save(@"C:\Users\peter\Documents\VS 2010 Projects\ExcelOutput2\www\test.xlsx");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something similar to this to generate and download the `Excel Sheet`.

```
protected void generateExcelSheet_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create Excel Sheet
    var sheet = new Worksheet("Hello, world!");
    sheet.Cells[0, 0] = "Hello,";
    sheet.Cells["B1"] = "World!";
    var workbook = new Workbook();
    workbook.Add(sheet);

    // Save
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelSheet.xls");
    workbook.Save(Response.OutputStream, CompressionLevel.Maximum);

    Response.End();
}
```

In the `designer.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FileDownload.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnExcel" runat="server" Text="Download Excel Sheet" onclick="generateExcelSheet_click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I based this code on [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/how-to-download-a-file-in-asp-net/) tutorial.

Comment: That's great and does the trick, thanks @eanderson. The only question I need to resolve is that when I open the file, I get a message 'The file you are tying to open, "MyExcelSheet.xls", is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now? If I say yes, the file opens fine. Is this a security issue as I can't see a problem with the file extension?

Comment: Try changing content-type to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` or take a look at http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml They mention four different content-types you can try.

Comment: Sorry no, that gives the same result.

Comment: Try to rename the filename to `.xlsx`.

Comment: Yes, that did it. Should not be a problem saving as this type. It seems .xls will throw this message as a default (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948615)