# Open a file from varbinary data using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, shellexecute, varbinary

I just need an answer to the question mentioned below. But first let me provide you with the scenario

Scenario

I have created a webforms based asp.net application. The following are the components of the application

1. A table with a Varbinary(MAX) column.
2. A webpage with a gridview and a fileupload control.

I have written code for uploading / downloading any file using the fileupload component. This is working quite ok.

Question.

I am looking into the possibility of providing a feature of opening the file. Just to clarify, opening the file (as distinct from downloading the file) is to open the file depending on the type of file IE if .xls file then Excel, .doc then word etc. In other words use the registered program to open the file.

Is this possible in an asp.net application?
Are there security considerations that prevent this? (It seems very likely)

The fact is that I am an experienced winforms programmer but I am relatively new to asp.net.

Any answers/tips/additional information is most welcome

Thanks in advance

Nomad

Answer (score 1):

Check the following StackOverflow answer: [C# Asp.net write file to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072814/c-sharp-asp-net-write-file-to-client)

These are the 3 lines you'll need:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=yourfile.txt");
```

One important thing is you'll need to research the different Content Types for the different file extensions.  XLS/X, DOC/X, PDF, etc all have different ContentType strings (which are easily searched for).

The good news is, you're probably already storing your filename in the database, so you can just use string manipulation to get the file extension, then look it up from either a database listing extension and ContentType, or just creating a list and "hard coding" it in there.

Comment: Oh, and you may want to research the FileStream object in SQL Server.  It's designed for file storage and is optimized in many cases for performance vs varbinary.

Comment: Thanks Garrison. Isn't this for downloading the file? I want to open the file using the associated/registered application or program. Let me know if I am going wrong somewhere. Thanks

Comment: This will spawn a "save" menu in the browser, which will give the user the option to open or save it.  Are you trying to display it in a browser?

Comment: Okayyy. I understand. I am going to try this out.  thanks for your clarifying answer. No, I don't want to open it in the browser. I simply want to open it using the registered application.