# Asp.Net saving web page response as PDF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to save asp.net webpage response as pdf,but what it happens when i tried to open the generated pdf file,,it shows adobe reader could not open the file because it is either not a supported file or because the file has been damaged.

Here is the code i tried

**Response.ClearHeaders()

Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Report.pdf"))

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"**

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using iTextSharp to convert html to pfd?

Comment: Why not just navigate to the pdf? And let the user decide what to do with the pdf.

Comment: I am not using ItextSharp, simply use the response by follow this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072814/c-sharp-asp-net-write-file-to-client

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply set the response as pdf.
You can use a library like itexsharp to get a pdf version of the web page
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: But actually i tried a sample web page which consists of only one label,the above code generate pdf file. i followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072814/c-sharp-asp-net-write-file-to-clientk

Comment: in the link that you mentionned the pdf file is already on the server and he was seeking for a way to deliver it to the client.
In your case, need to parse the html generated by your asp page, convert the content to pdf and then transmit it to the client. In this case, itextsharp is the library that converts your asp page to a pdf file.

Comment: ok thanks,I have one more doubt if i want to convert to word instead of pdf,which one prefer to use? already i researched itextsharp not supported word format.