# ASP.NET WebAPI: Create writable stream in response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I struggle quite a complicated scenario to which I cannot find the answer.

I am trying to create a REST service with ASP.NET WebAPI which serves as a wrapper for file operations on a server. Therefore I am trying build an API like `System.IO.File` and System.IO.Directory.
With `System.IO.File` comes the method `Create` which opens a Stream to the newly created file. The stream is writable so that it can be used to write content to the new file.

For my purpose I need to achieve this behaviour for my service as well. So the response should return a writable stream to the client and the this way the client can write data to the server.

I tried using `StreamContent` but it cannot be used with a stream that is only writable. It says "Reading is not supported on this stream." along with throwing a `NotSupportedOperationException`.

Is there any way I can pass a writable stream back to my client?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you looking for, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072814/c-sharp-asp-net-write-file-to-client) will help ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think so. It just produces an OutputStream which cannot be written by the client.